# print variable from text in db for mail object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, actionmailer

I need to move my mail object from static to text retrieved from db.

before changes i had this:

```
@oggetto = "Aggiornamento Intervento per #{@cliente.nome} ".html_safe
```

and sending mail with

```
mail(to: destinatari, subject: @oggetto)
```

without problems.

If i put the same text in db and retrieve it with

```
@oggetto = Mailcontent.where(:action_name => action_name).first.oggetto.html_safe
```

in the mail the object it becomes

```
Subject:Aggiornamento Intervento per #{@cliente.nome}
```

How can i solve? i tryed to changing with

```
mail(to: destinatari, subject: @oggetto.html_safe)
```

without success!

in the mail body was the same problem but i solved the problem using

```
<%= render :inline => h(@body_db.html.html_safe), :layout => false %>
```

but i don't know how to solve the same problem in the mail object!

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Solved !!!

```
@oggetto = eval '"' + Mailcontent.where(:action_name => action_name).first.oggetto + '"'
```